# Interrupting $_POST to Preview Input

Tags: php, mysql, webforms

I have set up a database and have form data being submitted to it via $_POST in PHP, and I also have my page set up and working which pulls in the fields from the database and displays them. Not rocket science I know.

However what I want to do now is place a page inbetween the submission of the form and the insert in the database, to give the user a chance to check their entry.

I have created this page and used the $_POST data to display the data from the form (as it has not been entered into the database yet), however i'm wondering how, if the user approves the submission, I then INSERT it into the database. (I've tried running the INSERT query from the $_POST data on pressing a submit button, however because (I assume) ivew interrupted the flow between the original form submission and the INSERT query, all I get is a list of errors for unrecognised variables.

So what I have is this process:

form.php /user enters info using $_POST

preview.php /user is previewed info using $_POST and Session code starts (below)

submit.php /MySql query runs but returns all errors for undefined indexes

This is my session start code:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['preview'])) { 
    $_SESSION['company_name'] = $_POST['company_name'];
    etc etc - remaining form field names
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST data is not automatically passed on to other pages. Save the submitted data in the session and read it from there after the *confirmation page*, or insert all that data back into the page using `<input type="hidden">` elements, so they can be resubmitted as POST.

A very simple illustration of the process using sessions:

*form.php*

```
<form action="confirm.php" ...>
    ...
</form>
```

*confirm.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST;
?>

Please confirm:

Name: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>
...

<a href="save.php">Confirm</a>
```

*save.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
$data = $_SESSION['data'];

// save $data to database
```

Comment: hi and thanks. So i start my form submission with a session, and leave that session open until they approve the entry, but how would i go about 'saving' the submitted data along the way? Would running a session take care of that automatically?

Comment: The session is just a place to store the data temporarily. After the initial POST submit, you write the data to the session and present the user with the "confirmation page". If the user confirms, you read the data from the session and write it to the database. That's all.

Comment: ive just tried starting a session like this on my form page session_start(); if (isset($_POST['preview'])) { $_SESSION['company_name'] = $_POST['company_name']; etc etc for all $_POST variable names, but i'm still getting Undefined Index errors when i come to submit after the preview. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with 3 modes

- Display
- Verify
- Insert

The quick an easy way is just to have a GET parameter or a hidden field that says the last state of the form. First time you display it its set to `DISPLAY`. Form submits, your script looks at the field, knows that after `DISPLAY` comes `VERIFY`, and presents the verification page. User submits, script looks at the field, knows that after verify you insert into the database, and you preform the relevant query.

Not sure how you were doing it before, but I assume that you were redirecting or just having the user click a link, which lost all the $_POST data

Comment: Hi, what i experimented with doing was, on the preview page, having the user click a submit button, which launches the original php file which captured all the post data and ran the INSERT query. Thanks so much for your answer, not sure i understand it, but i appreciate the time taken. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but is the form displayed on the preview page? A submit button with no form doesn't help much

Comment: ha, no it isn't. It's enclosed in a form action tag, but not the actual form.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying/doing, I'd do something like this:

When the user clicks the "save" (or whatever) button, hijack that click event and use the form data to do the preview business. When they click "confirm", have that send the data to the server and save it to the database.

Again, I'm not 100% sure if that will work, but perhaps it's a place to start.

Good luck!

Comment: @inkeddm hi, that's what i'm doing at the moment but it doesn't work because i've inserted a page between the orginal form submission and the INSERT query